# SQL Server OUTPUT inserted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to apply a condition on an output.inserted statement?

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE (foo INT)
DECLARE @tblOut TABLE (bar INT)

INSERT INTO @tblA 
OUTPUT inserted.foo INTO @tblOut(bar) --WHERE foo = 1
VALUES (1),(2),(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to apply condition on `OUTPUT` directly, but you can achieve what you need using output of the `MERGE`:

```
INSERT INTO @tblOut(bar)
SELECT foo
FROM (
    MERGE INTO @tblA t
    USING (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) s(foo)
    ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (foo)
        VALUES (s.foo)
    OUTPUT inserted.foo
) m
WHERE m.foo = 1;
```

Comment: thanks for this, i'm inserting into a pretty big table 30 million+ rows just concerned over the merge performance. I sometimes rarely there will be a couple of rows with criteria i need to insert into another table

Comment: @davey, I recall that I read some materials comparing "insert vs insert via merge" performance showing that they are quite comparable (such as this [one](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MERGE/103127/), for example). I'm not sure, however about effect of the applied filter and second output. It is better to test probably, with some smaller amount of rows.

Comment: Thanks its defintely a solution but I may try an alternative approach. Think I'm just going to grab the values i need after the insert into the new table

Comment: Be more concerned about the bugs in the MERGE statement. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/